# How to change the development branch in BitBucket?

Tags: bitbucket

How do I change the development branch for my BitBucket repository? Right now my `master` branch is labeled as both the `main` and the `development` branch.

[image]

This is a near duplicate of this question: [How to change the main branch in BitBucket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37550492/how-to-change-the-main-branch-in-bitbucket) however, I couldn't find anything telling me how to change the label for the development label and since it is different enough, I thought it warranted its own post for anyone in the future looking for this answer. (the top answer there is pretty clear so I copied the format he used)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

1. Repositories

[image]

2. Select repository
3. Click Repository settings (bottom of menu)

[image]

4. In the menu under WORKFLOW select `Branching model`

[image]

5. Should see a screen that looks like this at the top

[image]

6. Click the dropdown menu under `Development branch` and change it to `Use specific branch`.
   After that you should be able to click the dropdown menu next to it and change it to whatever branch you want

[image]

7. Make sure to hit save at the bottom

[image]

8. After saving it might take like 30 seconds but when you go back to your branches they should now have the `DEVELOPMENT` label changed to the branch you specified

[image]

I do not know how to do this from the terminal.

Comment: Keep in mind you'll need to have appropriate privileges/permissions for your account user in Bitbucket to even be able to view "Repository Settings" as mentioned.

Comment: A comment addressed to you was mistakenly posted as an answer: "Step 7. presents a list of branches to select from (e.g. "dev" in above example), however the OP (and me) are asking how to populate that custom branch list ? How do you get "dev" or "my fave branch" in the list?"

Comment: @Adriaan I am not sure I understand what you are saying. I answered my own question. The posted answer and OP are both me and I did in fact answer the question I myself was asking.

Comment: The "answer" was since deleted, hence you don't see it. The quotation in my previous comment is coped directly from the now-deleted answer. That's the part where they want an answer to. I don't understand any of the involved technologies, in this case I'm just the messenger. Full copy of that deleted answer, including image links, below. Author was [user22391861](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22391861/user22391861)

Comment: The OP asks "how to change the label for the development label" yet the prior answers do not specifically address.  e.g. how does one get "dev" or "my fave branch" in the list ? (per here https://i.stack.imgur.com/vobEV.png) To do this, one must have already added the new custom branch as per the following  https://i.stack.imgur.com/6QMwQ.png